# Unity Banner Ad not showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

My Unity Banner Ad is showing in the editor in `play mode` but not in the `build`. 
The Ad script is not set to testmode.
Placement id in operate dashboard is set to "bannerad"

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class BannerAdScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string gameId = "3658441";
    public string placementId = "bannerad";
    public bool testMode = false;

    void Start()
    {

        // Initialize the SDK if you haven't already done so:
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
        Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        Advertisement.Banner.Show(placementId);
    }


}
```

Why is the banner not showing and how can i fix this?

Comment: does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**If your Ad works in Test mode it can work, however:**

The Banner ads itself are pretty new and are still getting campaigns and more coverage for Europe, the engineer at Unity told me that NA was covered and they aim to have Europe covered by the end of this year, preferably until the end of Q3 but couldn't quite give me an official ETA, so take that with a grain of salt.